# Laravel 5.1 formfacade can't get value from select

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5.1, insert-update

I have created a form to change the user name and its role in the website.

```
@extends('layout/layoutAdmin')
@section('content')
<div>
  <h1>{{ $user -> name }}<h1>
  <p>{{ $user -> email }}<p>
</div>
{!! Form::model($user, ['url' => 'admin/menu/user_profiles/' . $user->id,  'method' => 'PATCH']) !!}
<div class="row">
<div class ="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name', $user->name,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::label('role', 'Role:') !!}
   {!! Form::select('role', array('admin' => 'admin', 'super_admin' => 'super admin',
   'super_researcher' => 'super researcher', 'researcher' => 'researcher',
   'consultant' => 'consultant', 'user' => 'user'), $user->role)
    !!}
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-md-7">
   {!! Form::submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
 </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

@stop
```

Everything is correct with the controller and I can change the name just fine, but I cannot save a new value for the role. it always stays the same.
Could anyone tell me how to save the role value?

EDIT!!!!
I did not have role field as fillable!

Comment: How to save it? This form is posting to /admin/menu/user_profiles/ID... so in that route's controller you'd need to get the posted value of 'role' and save it to the user? Do you mean making the form sticky before actually saving?

Comment: so you are using a patch request to update an existing record, whats your route and controller method look like are you using a resful route?

Comment: @MikelBitson Yes, the Patch to the update function in  the controller is wokring fine as I can change the name of the user. I guess making it sticky is what I am looking for

Comment: @futureweb Route::patch('{user}', 'UserProfilesController@update'); this is working correctly, just cannot get the value of the dropdown

Comment: Can you show us the update function? You could quickly determine if the controller is getting the value of the dropdown by var_dumping the post data within this update function.

Comment: data dump is correct @MikelBitson
added the code to the original post, it just wont overwrite role, but overwrites user

Comment: could you describe the attributes of the db? Not sure what field type your role expects, but now your sending text i.e. admin usually it is a number

Comment: @davejal role is type string, but i got it working. I just forgot to add it as fillable type in the eloquent model